# SQL to remove (number) from column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table column, called members, contains 10k+ records
some of the member names have a number beside like : 
John Smith (12)
Jane Doe (3)

is there an sql statement that i can use to the remove '(number)' from all values in the column?

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Jane Doe (3)','(',1) n;  -- Jane Doe`

Answer (score 4):

If the opening paren is used *only* for numbers, then you could do:

```
update table t
    set name = substring_index(name, ' (', 1)
    where name regexp ' ([0-9]+)';
```

I would check this out as a `select` first:

```
select name, substring_index(name, ' (', 1)
from table t
where name regexp ' ([0-9]+)';
```

Comment: Thank  you, tweaked it a bit and it was flawless.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with string functions like below. Here's a working example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20544/1

```
SELECT LEFT(NAME,INSTR(NAME,'(') - 1) New_Name from test;
```